# Need help uploading multiple large files (40mb - 2GB) using foreach array

Tags: php, arrays, file-upload, split, chunks

I'm building an online course website where users can upload multiple course videos. Right now, I'm trying to upload multiple video files using the following  code:

```
//Video Upload Array
if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
    $name_array=$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $content_name = isset($_POST['content_name']) ? $_POST['content_name'] : "" ;
    $tmp_name_array=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $type_array=$_FILES['file']['type'];
    $size_array=$_FILES['file']['size'];
    $error_array=$_FILES['file']['error'];
    for($i=0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++){
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], "course_content/".$courseid."/".$name_array[$i])){
            $sql="INSERT INTO sunriseadmin_db.course_content (course_info_id, content_filename, content_name) VALUES ('$courseid', '$name_array[$i]','$content_name[$i]')";
            $result=mysql_query($sql);
        }else{
            //echo "move file function failed for ".$name_array[$i]."<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to upload smaller files (1mb - 40mb) but I get connection reset error message if I try to upload multiple (4 or more) large files. I need help in figuring out how I can split the array into more manageable uploadable pieces up to 2GB.

Answer (score 0):

change php.in file  for localhost or live server

upload_max_filesize 1024M 
post_max_size  1024M

Comment: Thanks for the help! Im still getting a connection reset error when uploading about 7  videos totaling about 120MB. Here is whats in my php.ini:     file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 1024M 
post_max_size = 1024M
max_execution_time = 0